# BIRT Report Designer slow: Only one Thread on Multi Core Processor?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, birt

I am building some reports in Ecplise Report Designer (version 4.6.2), and the designer is terribly slow. For instance, if I drag a large data set (some 50 columns) into the layout as a table and then proceed to delete columns, it can take up to five minutes(!) to actually delete the columns and re-set the width of the table. Running the report as PDF or HTML only takes a few seconds, which means that the problem can't arise from the underlying data (which is based on rather efficient MySQL data bases).

When I check the CPU usage of the Report Designer in Windows Task Manager, it shows a high workload only on one of the eight threads, RAM usage is normal. Is there a way to tell the Report Designer to use more than just one thread? I am running Windows 7 64bit with a Core i7-3770 @ 3.4 GHz and 8GB RAM.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Johannes

Answer (score 0):

No. I think some of the delete actions are not optimally implemented.
If your data set has a lot of column, dragging it as a table into the layout doesn't make sense.
Instead, you should insert a table item (or list item) to the layout at the place where you want it with the context menu, then bind the item to the database.

Comment: Thanks for this idea, I will try to keep that in mind!